# ImportError: cannot import name 'ClusterDef'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

About a week ago I was able to import tensor flow but now I seem to have a problem running the same code. When I run either of these I am not able to get it to work at this point (what surprises me the most is at least part of it worked last week, now it does not seem to work), I get ImportError: cannot import name 'ClusterDef' which I am not finding anything online on:

```
import tensorflow
import keras   


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a649b509054f> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     75 
     76 # Bring in subpackages.
---> 77 from tensorflow.python.estimator import estimator_lib as estimator
     78 from tensorflow.python.layers import layers
     79 from tensorflow.python.ops import image_ops as image

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator_lib.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 # pylint: disable=unused-import,line-too-long
---> 22 from tensorflow.python.estimator.estimator import Estimator
     23 from tensorflow.python.estimator.export import export_lib as export
     24 from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs import inputs

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in <module>()
     48 from tensorflow.python.training import monitored_session
     49 from tensorflow.python.training import saver
---> 50 from tensorflow.python.training import training
     51 from tensorflow.python.util import compat
     52 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/training.py in <module>()
    180 
    181 # Distributed computing support.
--> 182 from tensorflow.core.protobuf.tensorflow_server_pb2 import ClusterDef
    183 from tensorflow.core.protobuf.tensorflow_server_pb2 import JobDef
    184 from tensorflow.core.protobuf.tensorflow_server_pb2 import ServerDef

ImportError: cannot import name 'ClusterDef'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is usually two reasons for ImportError

- it's circular import attempt
- the target object does not exist

in your case i would check if this file really contains ClusterDef class

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/core/protobuf/tensorflow_server_pb2.py
```

this is dynamically generated protobuf files (by grpc), which could somehow got deleted
in case this file does not contain needed class the best option is probably reinstall tensorflow/anaconda